# can a Virtual machine help me!

Tags: virtual-machine

I have Windows XP 64bit, and have experienced problems with a scanner driver which is not compatible with 64 bit systems. If I install Microsoft Virtual PC, and install a 32bit version of XP onto the virtual HD, will I be able to use my scanner using the Virtual PC?

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) instead. From what I remember, support for USB wasn't that great in VirtualPC. And VirtualBox seems better, in my opinion.

The scanner will work in the VM, as long as the OS is 32 bit and you have drivers for it.

Comment: thanks very much. Although, I'm not sure VirtualBox will run on a 64 bit system - have you any experience with this?

Comment: It runs on a 64bit OS, no problem. There's a download link on the site that says **VirtualBox 3.0.4 for Windows hosts x86/amd64**. AMD64 is a term used for 64 bit machines. Also, in the user manual, there's this: **Presently, we support Windows (primarily XP) and many Linux distributions on 32-bit hosts and on 64-bit hosts**

Comment: excellent, I appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help you out.

Comment: Support for USB is nonexistent in Virtual PC 2007, but it's available in Windows Virtual PC for Windows 7.

Comment: I knew that, but I wasn't 100% sure. That's why I recommended VirtualBox. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell us which scanner? Maker and model would be helpful, maybe someone here has used that particular device or knows a bit about 64-bit driver release for particular manufacturers.

In general though, your reasoning seems correct.

Comment: its a umax 2100xl, I've had a reasonably good look for 64bit drivers but havn't had any success.

Any help would be appreciated! Many thanks